# Spring FeignClient getting NullPointer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-cloud-feign

I am creating a feign client. I am getting a null pointer exception on the client. To isolate the issue from my current project, I created a console app project with a feign client that access a public api like Github. I still got the same issue. 
Can anyone point me an example (preferably using the maven instead of gradle)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already read other posts you can try adding:

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration(FeignAutoConfiguration.class)
```

to the main class. 
If it doesn't help please provide more details (like POM, error log etc)